# 超 vs めっちゃ + explanation

Tags: word-choice, words, dialects, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Significance of the kanji 「茶」 in the set phrase 「滅茶滅茶 / 目茶目茶」 {めちゃめちゃ}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/666/significance-of-the-kanji-in-the-set-phrase)

So, in Kansai they use めっちゃ, and in Kanto 超. But what about the other parts of Japan? And from where to where exactly do they use these words?
Can you also tell me where these words came from? Derived from what word or so (especially for めっちゃ, since 超 has a kanji and a meaning.)

Comment: You are asking a lot in one question….

Comment: As @Mark pointed out: めちゃ was already covered in a previous question. ちょう was [also discussed previously](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/972/is-ch-seldom-used-in-written-works). Furthermore, as @Tsuyoshi pointed out, your formulation is too general for a question. +1 Vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Mecha　has kanji and was explained in another thread　[Significance of the kanji 茶 in the set phrase 滅茶滅茶{めちゃめちゃ} / 目茶目茶{めちゃめちゃ}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/666/significance-of-the-kanji-in-the-set-phrase)